# Which technology is best to making video player?

Tags: html, flash, apache-flex, video, video-player

I am creating the Video player for my site. I like to use either Flash or Flex for making video player for my site which is embed into my HTML site.

**My Question**:

I am confusing to choose the technology for making the video player with good style,skin,functionality and easy to make.

**Functionality:**

I am going to make video player which have security of video url. Which user can not find the url of video(or encoded Video url). Also, display some advertisement on the Video player.

Also, no user can copy and use my embed/Object code to their site using tools like, firebug.

Will any one please help/suggest me for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should create jquery plugin which can generate player like http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/12/jwplayer.html5.js

This is jwplayer.

But for security, we can not prevent user from finding its source but you can use additional steps to make it hard to do so with

1. when using video id use it as encrypted one.
2. Add random string with URL
3. Use CRSF token per video so each video can be played only on your domain.
4. Use hotlink protection for your video directory from server side which will allow you not to load video other than your domain in case if some user finds video path accurately.